# Adding IP Address to Email Validation RegEx

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I am using the RegEx `"^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,17})$"`to validate Email but my lead want to validate as per the Microsoft standard. SO i need to follow

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.100).aspx

In that everything working fine as per the standard but still i am facing the issues with

Valid: js#internal@proseware.com
Valid: j_9@[129.126.118.1]

the above mentioned mail ID is still returning as invalid. I tried using the regex used in that  page

```
^(?("")(""[^""]+?""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,17}))$
```

but i am getting the error in the server page. Though I pasted the expression inside the validation Expression it can't able to accept the characters.

Note : am using ASP.Net validators for validating the email.

Comment: Tried that Regex also, and can't get it to work on any of the emails: http://regexr.com?35vs5

Comment: Yeah you are right.try this "^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,17})$" this will work but not for the above mentioned two Emails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

To match both of those email addresses in your sample text, I think I would rewrite your expression like this:

`[A-Z0-9._%#+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\])`

[image]

If you're looking to use this to validate a string which may contain only an email then you can add the start/end of string anchors `^` and `$`.

## Example

[Live Demo](http://www.rubular.com/r/o1ej22cp4w)

**Sample Text**

```
Valid: js#internal@proseware.com Valid: j_9@[129.126.118.1]
```

**Matches**

```
[0][0] = js#internal@proseware.com
[1][0] = j_9@[129.126.118.1]
```

Comment: Thanks Denomales, it really helps me .on top it i am testing the email formats in MS site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf(v=vs.100).aspx 
 for that i am using two regular expression one is [A-Za-z0-9._]+@\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\]and the other is [a-zA-Z_0-9#-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,17})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,17}) .Is that fine using two if loops to get that validated or i can shrink it down to one